# for loop assingment javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have a `swappedName` variable:

```
let swappedName = "elZerO";
```

I want to change the invert the case for each character in the string. My expected output is:

```
let result = "ELzERo"
```

I have to do this using only a `for` loop. How do I do this?

Comment: You should add your attempt. What is the problem you encounter? How is the output you get different? Did you debug your code? Inspected variables? ...etc

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked up how to iterate over characters in a string? Have you looked up how to convert case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sequentially loop through the string and append the inverted character to another string.

You can check whether the character is lowercase or not by converting it to lowercase (with `String.toLowerCase`) and checking whether the result is equal to the original.

```js
let swappedName = "elZerO";

let res = "";
for (let i = 0; i < swappedName.length; i++) {
  const current = swappedName.charAt(i);
  res += current == current.toLowerCase() ? current.toUpperCase() : current.toLowerCase();
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @AhmedMohsen No problem. If it solves your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :)